# Font looks crap when making font size small in Sublime Text

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 with "Consolas" as my default font.

Consolas looks good and nicely bold when I change the font-size to 15 and looks crappy when I change the font size to <15! Here are the screenshots:

Sublime Text with font size 15:
[image]

Sublime Text with font size 12:
[image]

As you can see font-size 12 looks absolute crap. The font-rendering is so bad. I mean it's not as boldish as it was with font-size 15. I tried `"font_options":["bold"]` which made it really worse.

How can I adjust the same beautiful bold size of font-size 15 when I'm on font-size 12?

Comment: have you tried `"font_options": ["dwrite_cleartype_natural"]`?

Comment: @KeithHall Just tried. Still looks same :(

Comment: @KeithHall Is there a option like scaling the code editor?

Comment: `ui_scale` - take a look in the default preferences to see how it works. You could also try `"font_options": ["directwrite", "dwrite_cleartype_natural"]` or `"font_options": ["gdi"]` although the latter isn't recommended.

Comment: Try adding `"subpixel_antialias"` or `"gray_antialias"` to `"font_options"` in your User preferences.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Didn't work :(

Comment: Do you have ClearType enabled on your system? I just saw this: https://www.slant.co/topics/67/viewpoints/11/~best-programming-fonts~consolas and https://blog.codinghorror.com/consolas-and-cleartype/.